# How to display a piece of code on my website like the way Stack Overflow does?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to securely display codes on my website. I am using Bootstrap on front end and PHP on server side.

My site has a comment box.

If I enter something as following then the whole webpage gets distorted. I want to detect that the text is a code and display it with a greyish background just like Stack Overflow.I am creating a blog like website in which on the home page I am displaying first 300 characters. So if I use code tag then the opening tag remains there but there is no closing tag and I end up distorting my website. I am also trying to integrate text editors like TinyMCE and CKEditor.

```html
<div class="text-muted">
```

Comment: So, open source code for stackoverflow page and see how it is done.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown SE uses a type of markdown editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the use of `pre` and HTML entites and apply some CSS for styling:

```css
pre {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:10px;
 background:linear-gradient(#eff0f1,#eff0f1) 8px 8px/calc(100% - 16px) calc(100% - 16px) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<pre>
&lt;a class="link"&gt; this a link &lt;/a&gt;
&lt;p&gt; this some content &lt;/p&gt;
</pre>
```

then you can consider some JS if you want to automatically change the `<` `>`

```js
let content = $('pre').html();
content = content.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
content = content.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
$('pre').html(content);
```

```css
pre {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#eff0f1, #eff0f1) 8px 8px/calc(100% - 16px) calc(100% - 16px) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<div class="container" data-attr="some data">
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/" >
<a class="link"> this a link </a>

<p> this some content </p>
</div>
</pre>
```

These are very simplified examples and you can find on the net many library that allow you to apply advanced styling:

Comment: The content is dynamic. If it would have been static then it would work.

Comment: @SamratV see the update ;)

Comment: Afif can you tell me what should I do if I wish to display codes of other programming language like Java, Python or C

Comment: @SamratV you do the same :) C or Python are easier since there is no `<` and `>` so simply put the code inside pre ;) or also use the code tag

Comment: @SamratV here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/39jpfqb3/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<pre></pre>` or `<code></code>` Tags to wrap your code samples. Then you insert your code with PHP between the tags. Be careful to escape all html tags - in PHP you can use htmlentities() to escape your output.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php

```
<?php
    $code = "<p>This is some <b>html</b> code";
    // safely display the code in the website:
    echo("<pre>" . $code . "</pre>");
?>
```

If you prefer something more sophisticated (like systax highlighting), have alook at this open-source solution: https://ace.c9.io/