# Where is the code StackOverflow uses to format code snippets?

Tags: javascript, code-formatting

I'm trying to learn how StackOverflow formats javascript and html code which was asked here [How to display a piece of code on my website like the way Stack Overflow does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719488/how-to-display-a-piece-of-code-on-my-website-like-the-way-stack-overflow-does) so I can do this on my website.

That question was closed because it was too broad, so I'm creating a more specific question.

**Which repo is used to hold the code that does the formatting for StackOverflow.com?**

**<del>Is it reusable, ok, too broad...</del>**

I did a google search

https://www.google.com/search?q=what+repo+is+used+to+format+code+for+StackOverflow.com

and nothing useful showed up.

I went to GitHub and searched for stackoverflow and found StackExchange which has 32 public repos, so I'm close.

If anyone knows which one is correct, you've answered this question.

BTW, I think it is pagedown (at https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown).

If I keep digging I'll probably figure this out but I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: I personally like QuillJs if you're trying to find an easy to use syntax highlighter.

Comment: This question has been CLOSED because it is asking for a `recommendation` (I think).   How would I change this question?  I don't read it as asking for a recommendation.

Comment: It's probably because it's a meta question and should have been asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I can see that someone might believe this question is a "Meta" question asking about the SO infrastructure, and since I got an answer to my question, I'll accept the decision and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org) per the comment on this answer, and according to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter). It used to use [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14681/191703).

Comment: Actually they switched to highlight.js. See this meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter